# How to Iterate Over String using next?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration

There's a string:

```
x = '012846871'
```

how would I loop so it would give me how many 1's are in the string:

```
010000001
```

as in like x[0] has no 1's, x[1] has one 1 and so on.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions/topics in here, most of which are unclear. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generator expression, for example something like this should work:

```py
x = '012846871'
mask = ''.join('1' if digit == '1' else '0' for digit in x)
print(mask)

>>> 010000001
```